# Error in Google Sign in for the Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am using "Google Sign-in for the Assistant" for Account Linking, and implement the Google Sign-In only flow. At the first time when user invoke an app (e.g: "Talk to my Test App"), it works fine ask for permission for taking name, profile picture, email from the google and Successfully get the info. But when i invoke an app second time it does not responding and receiving error in the logs: ***"App with account linking returned authentication error. Removing stored OAuth token."*** i didn't understand whats happening here, following is my code i am using as a webhook,

```js
const app = actionssdk({
  debug: true
})

app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'))
  conv.ask('Hello')
})

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask(`Hello test version`)
})

app.intent('actions.intent.SIGN_IN', (conv, input, signin) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    const payload = conv.user.profile.payload
    conv.ask(`I got your account details, ${payload.name}. What do you want to do next?`)
  } else {
    conv.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to do next?`)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app makes a user sign in every time a user launches your app. So if a user is a returning user (second time), system tries to remove/recreate profile about the user because that person is already signed in. So you should write in a way that the user does not fall into the sign in flow after the second time.

```
app.intent('welcome', conv => {
     const payload = conv.user.profile.payload;
     if (!paylaod) {
         return conv.ask(new SignIn('to sign in);
     }
     conv.ask('hi! ${payload.given_name}, how are you?')
})
```

This might work fo you.